# What is the datatype of the pinMode function?

Tags: pins, digital, data-type

I just tried it, but the Arduino IDE crashed, I hope its not related.
I want to declare a datatype like this:

```
int a = pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
```

or something like that, but I'm not sure what datatype the `pinMode` function uses. I looked on the [pinMode documentation page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/pinMode), of the Arduino website, and I see basic usage, but not a more clear definition of the source code for that function.

Answer (score 2):

`pinMode(pin, Mode);` is a `void`. It doesn't return anything. It simply sets a pin as an `OUTPUT` or an `INPUT`.

It says it in the link you posted.

> Returns
>
> None

That means that the function doesn't return any value.